# Travis CI: How to set environment variables for deployment script only?

Tags: travis-ci

In my `.travis.yml` configuration, I'd like to set up deployment to different stages (development/production) depending on the branch that triggered the build. I'm using a shell script to deploy, i.e., the `script` provider.

The question: I need to pass a different environment variables for different stages (mostly AWS keys). And these variables need to be encrypted when stored in version control. So, I'd like to do something like this:

```
deploy:
  - provider: script
    script: ./deploy.sh development
    env:
      -secure: <encrypted AWS_* variables for dev>
    on:
      branch: master
  - provider: script
    script: ./deploy.sh production
    env:
      -secure: <encrypted AWS_* variables for prod>
    on:
      branch: release
```

The `env` key can be used only globally, however. Is it possible somehow to specify the environment only for the specific script and not anything else?

Comment: I've been trying to figure out how to handle a similar situation. Were you able to figure this one out?

Comment: I have the same requirement for deploy my NPM by setting `NPM_CONFIG_TAG=next` to change `publishConfig.tag` which should be decided by the current version number.

Answer (score 1):

You accomplish this by restricting an environment variable to a specific branch when you [define it using the repository settings](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#defining-variables-in-repository-settings) in the web interface (I don't know how to do this using your `.travis.yaml`). You can create multiple variables with the same name so long as they are restricted to different branches. In your case, create `AWS_SECRET_FOO` for `master` with your dev credential and `AWS_SECRET_FOO` for `release` with your production credential.

<sub>Regardless, it would be awesome if you could define deployment-specific env vars simply for convenience.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You could simply include env in the script tag, e.g. as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50836765/5939806).

All that changes when including encrypted envs is that rather than setting envs public you either add them encrypted to version control by `travis encrypt MY_SECRET_ENV=super_secret --add`[(Reference)](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#Defining-encrypted-variables-in-.travis.yml) or within the travis envs (e.g. via interface). In your case maybe:

```
deploy:
  - provider: script
    script: env SUPER_SECRET_AWS_VARS=<encrypted AWS_* variables for dev> ./deploy.sh development
    on:
      branch: master
  - provider: script
    script: env SUPER_SECRET_AWS_VARS=<encrypted AWS_* variables for prod> ./deploy.sh production
    on:
      branch: release
```

Comment: This still doesn't work because the other stages of code have access to the super secret environment variable (it might be a different name). So this isn't a good workaround since you don't gain anything security wise - the secret is still in the environment of the other jobs/tasks.