# Travis manually confirm next stage

Tags: travis-ci

I have a stage `test` and `production`. I would like to manually confirm the deployment to production. Is there way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of [Conditional Deployments](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment#Conditional-Releases-with-on%3A). This allows you to specify whether you push to `production` or `test`.
Combine it with e.g. a `check-live-deployment.sh`-script and differentiate between branches and/or tagged commits.

For example:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

contains() {
    if [[ $TRAVIS_TAG = *"-live"* ]]
    then
        #"-live" is in $TRAVIS_TAG
        echo "true"
    else
        #"-live" is not in $TRAVIS_TAG
        echo "false"
    fi
}

echo "============== CHECKING IF DEPLOYMENT CONDITION IS MET =============="
export LIVE=$(contains)
```

and `.travis.yml` for a `dev`/`staging`/`live`-deployment to Cloud Foundry:

```
sudo: false
language: node_js
node_js:
  - '8.9.4'
branches:
  only:
    - master
    - "/v*/"
script:
  - printenv 
before_install:
  - chmod +x -R ci
install:
  - source ci/check_live_deployment.sh
  - ./ci/check_live_deployment.sh
deploy:
  - provider: script
    skip_cleanup: true
    script: env CF_SPACE=$CF_SPACE_DEV CF_MANIFEST=manifest-dev.yml ci/deploy_to_cf.sh
    on:
      tags: false
  - provider: script
    skip_cleanup: true
    script: env CF_SPACE=$CF_SPACE_STAGING CF_MANIFEST=manifest-staging.yml ci/deploy_to_cf.sh
    on:
      tags: true
  - provider: script
    skip_cleanup: true
    script: env CF_SPACE=$CF_SPACE_LIVE CF_MANIFEST=manifest-live.yml ci/deploy_to_cf.sh
    on:
      tags: true
      condition: $LIVE = true
```

This example pushes to `dev` if branch is master && no tag is present, `staging` if its a tagged commit, and `staging`+`live` if it is a tagged commit on master (a release) and the deployment-condition is met.

Granted: 
Maybe not the prettiest solution, but it definitely works. And this is not Travis waiting for you to manually confirm live-deployment (which would kind of ridicule the whole automated deployment principle imo), but it is a way to guarantee, that you have to manually trigger the pipeline in a specific way.

Comment: The `check_live_deployment.sh` step is unnecessary. You can just check the condition if $TRAVIS_TAG contains "-live" with regex, like this: `if: tag =~ -live`