# travis, upload generated pdf file only on tag

Tags: git, github, travis-ci, pdflatex

I always manage my latex projects with git. Now I thought I could somehow use Travis to build a PDF from the latex documents.

This also works under the following .travis configuration.

```
sudo: required
branches:
  only:
    - master
language: latex
services:
  - docker
before_install:
  - docker pull blang/latex:ubuntu
script:
  - make docker-pdf
before_deploy:
  - git config --local user.name "my-name"
  - git config --local user.email "my-email"
  - git tag "$(date +'%Y%m%d%H%M%S')-$(git log --format=%h -1)"
deploy:
  provider: releases
  api_key:
    secure: [my-key]
  file: "index.pdf"
  skip_cleanup: true
env:
  global:
    secure: [my key]
```

However, each commit is built and released. That's not the behavior I want you to have. I would like all commits to be built, but if I upload a tag, it will be published.

So I edit configuration on some points

```
before_deploy:
  - git config --local user.name "my-name"
  - git config --local user.email "my-email"
#  - git tag "$(date +'%Y%m%d%H%M%S')-$(git log --format=%h -1)"
deploy:
  provider: releases
  api_key:
    secure: [my-key]
  file: "index.pdf"
  on:
    tags: true
  skip_cleanup: true
```

But I get the following message from travis.

```
The command "make docker-pdf" exited with 0.
Skipping a deployment with the releases provider because this is not a tagged commit
```

But I pushed a commit. So I dont understand the behavior.

Volker

Comment: You've pushed a commit, but have you pushed a tag with it?

Answer (score 0):

If you've actually pushed a tagged commit including

```
on:
  tags: true
```

it should have done the trick..

Did you tag & push the way described [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging)? Pay attention to the `push origin`:

```
git tag -a v1.4 -m "my version 1.4"
git push origin v1.4
```

> By default, the git push command doesn’t transfer tags to remote servers. You will have to explicitly push tags to a shared server after you have created them. This process is just like sharing remote branches — you can run git push origin .

---

Maybe include a simple echo in your `script` or `before_install`, to verify that `$TRAVIS_TAG` is actually set. Pay attention to [this part of the documentation](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#Default-Environment-Variables), regarding the default environment variables. So just include:

```
- echo $TRAVIS_TAG
```

If it still does not work somehow, you might also check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50836765/5939806). It includes information about deployment regarding tags and further options.