# Have Travis deploy on a tag regex with a custom condition

Tags: travis-ci

I am trying to get Travis to deploy on tags, that match a pattern `/v.*/`, and have an environment variable set to a particular value `$GITSECRET_DIST == deb`. I have tried the following:

```
skip_cleanup: true
    on:
      branches:
        except:
        - legacy
        - experimental
      tag: true
      condition: "$TRAVIS_TAG =~ ^v.*$ && $GITSECRET_DIST == rpm"
```

The results at https://travis-ci.org/simbo1905/git-secret/jobs/394177628 is:

```
Skipping a deployment with the bintray provider because this branch is not permitted: v0.0.4
```

I also tried:

```
skip_cleanup: true
    on:
      branches:
        only:
        - master
        - /v.*/
      tag: true
      condition: "$TRAVIS_TAG =~ ^v.*$ && $GITSECRET_DIST == rpm"
```

That gave at https://travis-ci.org/simbo1905/git-secret/jobs/394169491:

```
Skipping a deployment with the bintray provider because this branch is not permitted: v0.0.3
```

I also tried without any branch specifications.

How do I get it to build on tag, that matches an regex, with a custom condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting `all_branches: true` worked:

```
skip_cleanup: true
on:
  all_branches: true
  tag: true
  condition: "$TRAVIS_TAG =~ ^v.*$ && $GITSECRET_DIST == rpm"
```

Answer (score 1):

It might not exactly suit your needs, since it does not use regex directly in the `condition` section of `.travis.yml`, however: I've elaborated on one way to accomplish this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50836765/5939806).

You should be able to modify the script according to your needs. And if you really want to make use of regex, you can also do it in the script, e.g. like [this](https://www.networkworld.com/article/2693361/operating-systems/unix-tip-using-bash-s-regular-expressions.html).