# Travis for CI/CD

Tags: continuous-integration, travis-ci, continuous-deployment

We are planning to move from jenkins to travis for all our micro services and had a question when it comes to CD to different environments.

For example, we have a `micro-service` git repository with just `master` branch and 3 different environments on aws - `dev`, `test` and `production`. We can successfully build a docker image and push it to aws ecr.

After going through multiple resources, looks like many of them suggest to have different git branches for deploying to different environments which in my opinion is an overkill.

Is there any alternative with which we can deploy to different environments without having multiple branches?

Answer (score 0):

How about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50836765/5939806) method?

It'll enable you to do this via untagged/tagged/specifically tagged commits.  Simply switch from the depicted Cloud Foundry example to your AWS deployment.